# Servlet request to another servlet with authorization

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have tomcat server with some applications. This server uses standart j_secure_check auth. On another tomcat server I need to deploy application that must be some proxy to first server. So I need to invoke servlet from another servlet but first I need to do authentication with j_secure_check. Is it possible to do it programmely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to grab the session cookie and pass it through on subsequent requests.

```
String url = "http://example.com/j_security_check?j_username=foo&j_password=bar";
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();

if (connection.getResponseCode() == 200) { // 200 = OK, 401 = unauthorized
    String cookie = connection.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie").split(";", 2)[0];

    url = "http://example.com/somepage.jsp";
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
    connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
    // You can now write it to response.getOutputStream().
}
```

Comment: but it's going to a different server?

Comment: @ericacm: yes, the OP is talking about two Tomcat servers of which the one should act as a proxy for the other. The above code should then run on the server acting as proxy and the URL should point to the other server.

Comment: right, is the session cookie from the proxy going to work on the other server?

Comment: @ericacm: It's the session cookie of the other server, not of the proxy.

Comment: gotcha.  i misread the OP.  one question is, is the user supplying the username/password or is there one username/password for the proxy to use for all requests.

Comment: @ericacm: That's up to the OP to decide. It was just an example. I think the latter and that the server is actually inaccessible for the enduser since having a proxy wouldn't make much sense otherwise.